# Mongoose getters are either not working the way I want or I'm misunderstanding what they are

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I created some sample code to demonstrate my issue on a smaller scale. From my understanding, a getter function will not affect anything on my database, but when I want to make a get request to view items on my database, it will change the value to whatever is returned only when the data is displayed. However, when I make my get request to view items on my database, the item I am shown is exactly how it was saved. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding what a getter function is, or if my syntax is just incorrect somewhere.

Here is my main server:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// Linking my model
const User = require('./User')

// Initializing express
const app = express()
const PORT = 9999
app.use(express.json())

// Connecting to mongodb
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdatabase', {
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true
        })
        console.log('Connected')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Failed to connect')
    }
}
connectDB()

// Creates a new user
app.post('/user/create', async (req, res) => {
    await User.create({
        name: 'John Cena',
        password: 'somepassword'
    })
    return res.json('User created')
})

// Allows me to view all my users
app.get('/user/view', async (req, res) => {
    const findUser = await User.find()
    return res.json(findUser)
})



// Running my server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on localhost:${PORT}...`)
})
```

Here is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// My setter - initialPassword is 'somepassword'
// This seems to work properly, in my database the password is changed to 'everyone has the same password here'
const autoChangePassword = (initialPassword) => {
    console.log(initialPassword)
    return 'everyone has the same password here'
}

// My getter - changedPassword should be 'everyone has the same password here' I think
// The console.log doesn't even run
const passwordReveal = (changedPassword) => {
    console.log(changedPassword)
    return 'fakehash1234'
}

// Creating my model
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        set: autoChangePassword,
        get: passwordReveal
    }
})

// Exporting my model
const model = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)
module.exports = model
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would help anyone since I found my answer on another StackOverflow post, but the issue was I had to set getters to true when converting back to JSON:

```
// Creating my model
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        set: autoChangePassword,
        get: passwordReveal
    }
}, {
    toJSON: { getters: true }
})
```

Any similar problems can be solved by adding some combination of the following:

```
{
    toJSON: {
        getters: true,
        setters: true
    },
    toObject: {
        getters: true,
        setters: true
    }
}
```